# Mixing php with html tags

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to implement the below code, but as a result get displayed nothing back.

```
 <li class="cleanup">Garantie:<span><?php (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true); ?> Jahre</span><?php echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true) >= 2) ? ('<span class="pro_con pro"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Lange Garantie: ' . <?php (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true)); ?> . ' Jahre</span>') : ('<span class="pro_con pro"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Standart Garantie: ' . <?php (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true)); ?> . ' Jahre</span>'; ?>) </li>
```

The field should be available and the function `get_post_meta` does work!

I assume that I have a syntax error, but I am not sure where?

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Maybe because you forgot to echo the returned value? Is the site blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis, change to

```
<?php get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true); ?>
//   ^ it was here
```

And by the way, you must have your logging on on devel env, logs help a lot.

Comment: Yes he probably forgot the echo thats why there are the parenthesis

Comment: `echo` could potentially be inside a `get_post_meta`.

Comment: No, he used one echo himself, probably copy and pasted it only partially

Comment: Meta: Functions starting with `get` shouldn't echo. It should be named `print_` instead if it echoes anything; but then again, it's Wordpress ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have some extra closing `?>` php tags inside the Ternary operator.

**Modified Code:**

```
 <li class="cleanup">Garantie:
 <span>
 <?php get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true); ?> Jahre
 </span>
 <?php 
 echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true) >= 2) ? 
 ('<span class="pro_con pro"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Lange Garantie: ' . 
 (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true)) . ' Jahre</span>') : 
 ('<span class="pro_con pro"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i>Standart Garantie: ' . 
    (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true)) . ' Jahre</span>' ) ;
?>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    <li class="cleanup">Garantie:<span><?php (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true); ?> Jahre</span>
<?php echo (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true) >= 2) ? '<span class="pro_con pro"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Lange Garantie: ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true) . ' Jahre</span>' : '<span class="pro_con pro"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Standart Garantie: ' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true) . ' Jahre</span>'; ?> </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
 <li class="cleanup">
    Garantie:
    <span>
        <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true); ?> Jahre
    </span>
    <?php 
        if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true) >= 2){
            echo '<span class="pro_con pro"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Lange Garantie: ';
            echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true);
        }else{
            echo '<span class="pro_con pro"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>Standart Garantie: ';
            echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Garantie', true);
        }
        echo " Jahre</span>";
    ?>
</li>
```

Afterall, readability counts...